# Trap and collect script output, "input file is output file" error?

Tags: bash, file-descriptors, error-handling, trap

I need to upload the output of the current script, so I added a `trap` and `set -ex`, e.g

```
#!/bin/bash

exec &> /tmp/error.log
trap 'cat /tmp/error.log; curl http://127.0.0.1/error.php?hostname=$(hostname) -F file=@/tmp/error.log' EXIT

set -ex
wtfwtf
```

When I execute it, I'm always getting this error, and the PHP script did not receive the whole file

```
%> cat /tmp/error.log
1.sh: line 6: wtfwtf: command not found
cat: /tmp/error.log: input file is output file
```

So far, the only solution is to copy the error.log to a new file and upload it, e.g

```
#!/bin/bash

exec &> /tmp/error.log
trap 'cp /tmp/error.log 123; curl http://127.0.0.1/error.php?hostname=$(hostname) -F file=@123' EXIT

set -ex
wtfwtf
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Do you need the `cat`?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Not really. The client is uploading an file partially so you'll want to `cat` the file and see what's being uploaded. So the `cat` command here is only for debugging

Comment: And the `cat` was the bug. What sort of bug, was it a spider cat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the `exec`, you are redirecting all output of the script to a specific log file.

In your trap, you want to display the contents of the log file using `cat`. Since all output is also redirected to that file, GNU `cat` notices that its input file and standard output stream (which is inherited from the shell) are the same thing, and refuses to perform its task.

BSD `cat` does not do the same check as GNU `cat` does, which, if the script is not interrupted, results in an infinitely large log file with the same few lines repeated over and over.

A workaround is to save the original standard output file descriptor, do the redirection as before, and then reinstate it in the trap.

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3>&1                  # make fd 3 copy of original fd 1
exec >/tmp/error.log 2>&1

# in the trap, make fd 1 copy of fd 3 and close fd 3 (i.e. move fd 3 to fd 1)
trap 'exec 1>&3-; cat /tmp/error.log; curl "http://127.0.0.1/error.php?hostname=$(hostname)" -F file=@/tmp/error.log' EXIT

set -ex
wtfwtf
```

This makes a copy of file descriptor 1 (as fd 3) before redirecting it to the log file. In the trap, we move this copy back to fd 1 and do the output.

Note that the standard error stream, in the trap, in this example, is still connected to the log file. Therefore, if the `curl` generates a diagnostic message, this will be saved in the log file rather than being displayed on the terminal (or wherever the original standard error stream was connected to).

---

Taking [the comment from Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/448323/trap-and-collect-script-output-input-file-is-output-file-error/448344?noredirect=1#comment813581_448344) into account:

```
#!/bin/sh

exit_handler () {
    # 1. Make standard output be the original standard error
    #    (by using fd 3, which is a copy of original fd 2)
    # 2. Do the same with standard error
    # 3. Close fd 3.
    exec >&3 2>&3 3>&-
    cat "$logfile"
    curl "some URL" -F "file=@$logfile"
}

logfile='/var/log/myscript.log'

# Truncate the logfile.
: >"$logfile"

# 1. Make fd 3 a copy of standard error (fd 2)
# 2. Redirect original standard output to the logfile (appending)
# 3. Redirect original standard error to the logfile (will also append)
exec 3>&2 >>"$logfile" 2>&1

# Use shell function for exit trap (for neatness)
trap exit_handler EXIT

set -ex
wtfwtf
```

His point is that the logfile is only for diagnostic messages anyway, so it makes more sense to output the logfile to the original standard error stream.

He also points out that it's dangerous to use a fixed filename in a world-writable directory such as `/tmp`.  This is because no check is put in place in the script to make sure that this file does not already exist (someone or some malware could have created a `/tmp/error.log` symlink to `/etc/passwd` or your `~/.bashrc` for instance).  His solution to this is to use a dedicated persistent log file for the script under `/var/log` instead (the file is persistent, but the contents will be cleared when running the script).

A variation of this would be to use `mktemp` to create a unique filename under `$TMPDIR` (and then remove that file in the `EXIT` trap, unless `curl` failed in which case the `rm` would not be executed since `set -e` is in effect):

```
#!/bin/sh

exit_handler () {
    # 1. Make standard output be the original standard error
    #    (by using fd 3, which is a copy of original fd 2)
    # 2. Do the same with standard error
    # 3. Close fd 3.
    exec >&3 2>&3 3>&-
    cat "$logfile"
    curl "some URL" -F "file=@$logfile"
    rm -f "$logfile"
}

logfile=$( mktemp )

# 1. Make fd 3 a copy of standard error (fd 2)
# 2. Redirect original standard output to the logfile (appending)
# 3. Redirect original standard error to the logfile (will also append)
exec 3>&2 >>"$logfile" 2>&1

# Use shell function for exit trap (for neatness)
trap exit_handler EXIT

set -ex
wtfwtf
```

---

Your second example works, but only because you're not using `cat` on the log file, not because of copying it.

---

Minor nitpick: URLs on the command line should probably always be at least double-quoted as they tend to contain characters that the shell may interpret as special (for example `?`).

Comment: where can i get more information about this exec ?

Comment: @Kamaraj Duplicating and moving file descriptors is described in the `bash` manual. The sections are called "Duplicating File Descriptors" and "Moving File Descriptors". You may also search the web for tutorials about this if the manual's description is too terse (I have no good examples of tutorials unfortunately).

Comment: Here, since it's errors we're talking about, it would make more sense to send them to the original stderr. Also note that using files with fixed names in a world writable directory is a very dangerous thing to do. I'd do: `log=/var/log/myscript.log; : > "$log"; exec 3>&2 >> /var/log/myscript.log 2>&1` and ... `trap 'exec >&3 2>&3 3>&-; ...` (and then you can even use `sh` instead of `bash`)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Much thanks.  I have incorporated that in the answer.

Comment: Note that you can also define your `exit_handler()` as `exit_handler() { ...; } >&3 2>&1 3>&-`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ah, that's handy! Thanks again!